# Why GORM doesn't generate FOREIGN CONSTRAINT for Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm new with Go and GORM. After generating my DB for testing, I don't see that the One To Many relationship is properly represented in Postgres.

I have created a couple of models to be migrated into Postgres, for example, these 2 specifically:

```
type PgPiece struct {
    ID             string `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name           string
    MinPrice       float64
    Likes          int
    Description    string
    Materials      string
    Techniques     string
    Width          float64
    Height         float64
    Length         float64
    Hours          int
    CreatedAt      *time.Time
    ModifiedAt     *time.Time
    IsFavorite     bool
    EstimatedValue float64
    Owner          PgUser `gorm:"foreignkey:OwnerID"`
    OwnerID        string
    Author         PgUser `gorm:"foreignkey:AuthorID"`
    AuthorID       string
    Favorites      []PgUser       `gorm:"many2many:user_favorite_piece"`
    Images         []PgPieceImage `gorm:"foreignkey:piece_id"`
```

}

```
type PgPieceImage struct {
    ID        string `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Url       string
    Position  int
    Width     int
    Height    int
    CreatedAt *time.Time
    Piece PgPiece `gorm:"foreignkey:PieceRef"`
    PieceRef   string `gorm:"column:piece_id"`
}
```

And as result I see this in postgres for PgPieceImage

```
CREATE TABLE public.piece_image
(
    id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    url text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "position" integer,
    width integer,
    height integer,
    created_at timestamp with time zone,
    piece_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT piece_image_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.piece_image
    OWNER to freddy;
```

Why there is non FOREIGN CONSTRAINT there?

Comment: I would ask: Why should there a FOREIGN CONSTRAINT? 
Did you  use the AutoMigration? Did you add the other table? http://doc.gorm.io/database.html#migration

Comment: @apxp yes. I added the AutoMigrate and both tables are there. The database was created with each table. For my foreign constraint, YES, I’m expecting to see this constraint in some how. As it is right now, they are just tables without any relationship between them if we just check the sql generated by the AutoMigrate call. I’m wondering if I’m doing something wrong or just GORM doesn’t generate a foreign constraint properly. Please, advise if it’s possible. Regards